# Open my mobile Java program with SMS, no SMS in inbox

Tags: java, mobile, sms

Is it possible to open my mobile Java program with an SMS?

And I don't want this SMS to be stored in the inbox. I'm looking for the kind of "Control SMS" that banks use for their mobile applications. I want the same in my application: send SMS to the mobile, the mobile device shows a message on screen that will be opened by the program, and this SMS should not be saved in the inbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that you're not mistaking push notifications/cloud to device messages for SMS's?

Push/C2D messages are similar to SMS's inasmuch as a central server sends a message out to devices and many apps then display a popup based on that message, but the implementation is completely different.  If you're not mistaking the two, is there a reason you'd prefer to use SMS's that are handled differently than most instead of push/C2D messages?

Here's the [documentation for Apple's Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).
Here's Android's [Cloud to Device Messaging documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) which serves the same purpose.
Have a look and see if that would serve your needs.

Comment: not mistaking, I want open my java program on every mobile device that can run java programs, with somthing like `SMS` but no Internet on mobile device

Comment: @hamze Thanks for clarifying, though I'm not sure that's possible.  Are you sure that's how the banking apps you mentioned are doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for completely client side J2ME based solution for feature phones - then try push registry. It is available above MIDP2. I don't know the exact details but there you can define event and triggers which will be stored by phone OS and invoked automatically when particular type of event occurs.
SMS sending is separate issue but there are tools available for that definitely.